# Are there any reasons to use Action.async other than readability in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I read the [official doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaAsync) of play async action and understand Action.async is

> just a facility to simplify creating actions based on APIs that return a Future.

What I am concerned is it seems to introduce unhandled errors if you blindly return the Future[Response] because Future might be Failure.

Of course, you can handle Failure case by something like

```
def index = Action.async {
  intensiveComputation()
    .map { i => Ok("Got result: " + i) }
    .recover { case e: Exception => InternalServerError("error")}
}
```

But you can also use Action by writing something like this and by consistently using Action over Action.async, you don't forget to handle error case.

```
def index = Action {
  intensiveComputation().onComplete {
    case Success(i) => Ok("Got result: " + i)
    case Failure(e) => InternalServerError("error")
  }
}
```

So if I don't want to introduce unexpected error, is it good practice to always use Action.apply? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries, *Play* provides a nice *Error Handling*.

In essence there is an Error Handler, that wraps the exceptions in according HTTP exceptions. Unhandled errors for example will be HTTP 500 exceptions.

You can also provide your own Error Handler.

See the [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaErrorHandling)  for more infos

Answer (score 1):

An high level answer:

Second approach will not even compile, as per my understanding, onComplete return type is Unit and Play action expects Request[AnyContent] => Result(in case of Action) or Request[AnyContent] => Future[Result] (in case of Action.async).

Hope that helps.